# Only the first ldb file of 3 is read

Tags: go, leveldb

When I open the database and read the contents, only the first ldb file is read. The rest remain untouched, although there is information there. using this [library](https://github.com/syndtr/goleveldb)

```golang
db, err := leveldb.OpenFile("db/1", &opt.Options{ReadOnly: true})
  if err != nil {
    //error handling
  }
  var data []string

  iter := db.NewIterator(nil, nil)
  for iter.Next() {
    data = append(data, string(iter.Key()))
    data = append(data, string(iter.Value()))
  }

  iter.Release()
  err = iter.Error()
  fmt.Println(err)

  defer db.Close()
```

files:
[image]

Comment: did you try reading them one by one

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV, I added the code in the question, there I read the base directory at once. How do you propose to read each file? Just by means of Go?

Comment: I do not understand the question: LevelDB (and this Go port of it) is a multi-level DB (hence the name), in which the number of files it maintains is an _implementation detail._ So what is the essense of the question? (Multi-level means it performs so-called "compaction" which really removes records marked as deleted and moves some remaining data across "levels".)

Comment: @kostix Here I opened the database, and only the first file 000005.ldb was read. The other files 008604.ldb and 008606.ldb are not read, although if you open them in the editor, they have data that is not in 000005.ldb.

Comment: You have just restated the original question, but this behavior of LevelDB is beside the point. Do you mean that, say, if you create a LevelDB (using that package) afresh, then, say, insert N (some big N) records into it, properly close the DB (it _has to_ be properly closed), open it again, you won't be able to read all those N back, but some smaller subset? I'm asking because we're using that exact package here at my $dayjob for a reasonably important piece of infrastructure, and had so far no such obvious (that is, basic) problems with it.

Comment: To say what I mean in other words, LevelDB [implements data compaction](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/main/doc/impl.md), and in general, any DB engine is free to choose whatever implementation it sees fit to store the data you put into it (and change that implementation between its versions). And what is actually stored in the DB's files may be deceiving. For instance, the DB may duplicate some data (when compacting), may mark some records as deleted but not physically delete them just yet, and so on. …

Comment: … So it's crucial to understand whether "some data is not being read" is your misinterpretation of what _should_ happen or actually a very basic bug in LevelDB (which is unlikely).

Comment: @kostix I think I understand what you want to say, look I ran before in read only mode, if I run in off read only mode, then files 008604.ldb and 008606.ldb are deleted, so are these files marked for deletion (or are they in error and therefore deleted)?